# Meaning of "Busted" as an adjective

Tags: meaning, adjectives

What does "busted" mean in this context?

> He also possesses a glass eye, an ear for heavy metal, and a *busted* internal radar.

In reference to character Michael Burry from the movie "The Big Short".

Comment: What does a dictionary tell you???  Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: "He also possesses a glass eye, an ear for heavy metal, and a busted internal radar. Socially, he makes Steve Jobs look like David Niven. (Bale can be such a chilly actor, but here he plays a chilly man, whose very gait spells bewilderment..." http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2015/12/14/hard-bargains The New Yorker, Dec 14, 2015.  According to the book, Burry has Asperger's.

Answer (score 6):

It's a slang term, but in this case it means broken or defective.

> **Adjective**
>   **busted** ‎(*comparative* **more busted**, *superlative* **most busted**)
>
> 5. (*slang*) Broken.
>
> <sub>Source: [Wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/busted)</sub>

It should also be noted that the term 'internal radar' here is used in the figurative sense:

> **Noun**
>   **radar** ‎(*countable and uncountable*, *plural* **radars**)
>
> 4. (*countable*, *figuratively*) A superior ability to detect something.
>
>    > *His sensitive radar for hidden alliances keeps him out of trouble.*
>
> <sub>Source: [Wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/radar)</sub>

So the whole phrase 'busted internal radar' refers to the characters inability to detect something that may be obvious to others.